# Show this holomorphic function is costant

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a holomorphic function $f$ defined on a neighborhood of the closed unit square.

Further $f(z+i)=f(z)$ on $[0,1]$ and $f(z+1)=f(z)$ on $[0,i]$.

How do I show that $f$ is constant?

Comment: Are you aware that the zeros of a homomorphic function must be isolated?

Comment: I still don't see why there are not-isolated zeros. Could you please tell me why this is the case?

Comment: Then append the other question or comment on an answer.

Comment: I was thinking that $f(z+i)-f(z)$ and $f(z+1)-f(z)$ are constant because of non isolated zeros. On further consideration, I'm not sure if this helps.

Comment: I couldn't comment in my own question because when I registered after posting as a guest, this question was not added to my account. It is a slightly different question though.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider $\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,dz$ where $C$ is the unit square and $a$ is in the interior of the unit square.